# Creating custom page templates

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have just created my "About Us" page inside WP Admin Dashboard, that points to an about-us.php page template that I created and has a empty div content, i.e.

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

It is in here where I would like to grab the content that the wp-admin user enters in the dashboard About Us page and place this content within my

```
<div id="content">[Dashboard About Us Page Content to go Here]</div>
```

Basically want to take the whole content from the "About Us" WordPress page and feed this into my about-us.php page template content DIV.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php if(have_posts()): while(have_posts()): the_post();
the_content();
endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Stick that inside the empty div and it will pull the content in dynamically. Read more about the loop here:

http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop